# trying to add an empty handle extractable

Tags: c++, cplex

I have a C++ Cplex with Concert Technology code and I receive this error:

Error: trying to add an empty handle extractable

This for loop is where I get the error. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
IloNumVarArray x(env, n, -IloInfinity, IloInfinity);

for (IloInt i = 0; i < n; i++){
            model.add(x[i]);        
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the variables in your array haven't been correctly initialized. Can you please make a null check of x[0] before the loop starts?

Comment: It's probably a bit unusual to simply add variables directly to a model. It is more normal to add the constraints to the model and that will implicitly add the associated variables. But I don't see why you couldn't add variables to the model.

Answer (score -1):

You may forget to define one of your elements like model inside `env`.

```
IloModel model(env);
```